# applescript getInputByClass2 with Safari 10.1

Tags: variables, safari, applescript

My Applescripts I used to run everyday to get text from Safari isn't working since my last system update

It used to work only in Safari, and not in Safari Preview, I guess the system for Safari Preview was bring to safari now/

```
tell application "Safari"

    set DinfoGrab to do JavaScript "
document.getElementsByClassName(' field type-string field-Dinfo ')[0].innerHTML;" in tab 3 of window 1
end tell
```

with this error :

> Safari got an error: Can’t make " document.getElementsByClassName('
>   field type-string field-Dinfo ')[0].innerHTML;" into type text.

how can I fix that? thanks.

UPDATE :

Here is something working perfectly with Chrome :

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
        tell tab 3 of window 1 to set r to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('field type-string field-Dinfo')[0].innerHTML;"
    end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the complete code, I can't say for sure what's going on. But judging by the name of your function -- `getInputByClass2` -- I assume you're trying to get the value of HTML `<input>` fields. If this is true, you should be using `outPut.push(arr[i].value)` instead of `outPut.push(arr[i].innerHTML)`

As for the second bit of code, your JavaScript doesn't have any error handling in case the value of `document.getElementsByClassName(' field type-string field-Dinfo ')[0]` is null.

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName(' field type-string field-Dinfo ');
//set to value of [0].innerHTML if [0] exists, else empty string
var html = els.length ? els[0].innerHTML : ""; 
//return value to AppleScript
html;
```

### update (response to updated question)

Running the following script in Script Editor against this StackOverflow page will return the correct value (assuming you have the correct window/tab numbers set). If the search field at the top of this StackOverflow page is empty, you will get an empty string. If you enter a term (but don't submit) then run the AppleScript, you will get the value of the field.

```
tell application "Safari"
    set DinfoGrab to do JavaScript "
document.getElementsByClassName('js-search-field')[0].value;" in tab 1 of window 1
end tell
```

The only changes from your script are the window/tab numbers, the classname (changed to match the StackOverflow page), and I used `value` instead of `innerHTML`.

I have tested in the most current version of Safari (10.0.3); if this doesn't work in your version of Safari, ensure you're pointing to the correct class name. If this script DOES work for you, then the issue is probably due to something on the page you're trying to search, perhaps related to the type of `<input>` field you're fetching or an incorrect classname. Maybe the update to Safari is causing the page to render differently, which indirectly affects your code.

Comment: Thank for the reply, the previous script used to work fine for around a year though, I tried anyway to change for .value instead but then I have  Safari got an error: Can’t make "
document.getElementsByClassName(' field type-string field-dsid ')[0].value;" into type text.

Comment: First thing I'd check is the typeof for document.getElementsByClassName(' field type-string field-dsid ')[0]: `alert(typeof document.getElementsByClassName(' field type-string field-dsid ')[0])`. At least then you'd know if `document.getElementsByClassName(' field type-string field-dsid ')[0])` is actually returning anything useful

Comment: I update the script with the same snipped with is working with Chrome, I guess it's an issue with my version of Safari. I don't manage to run your code neither, I should probably find sometime to learn more JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for the update, isn't ".value" for form and text field though ?  your script is working alright , along with my script with one of my other Mac (with StackoverFlow search) but not on my computer here, I have the error Safari got an error: Can’t make " .....  into type text. , Also I'm running Safari  10.1 (12603.1.29) I think is since 10.1 that I have the issue

Comment: Yes, `value` is for form `<input>` elements. As I mentioned in my answer, I'm assuming you're scraping `<input>` elements because your function is named `getInputByClass2`. If you're not scraping `<input>` elements, and are just scraping standard HTML elements like `<div>`, you'd use `innerHTML`.

Comment: I have verified my example works on Safari 10.1, macOS Sierra

Comment: I just can confirm it's a fresh bug, introduced in one of the recent Sierra betas. Everything was working fine with a similar script of mine until today, when I had to run it again and spent an hour dealing with this sudden cryptic error message "into type text." number -1700 from" (just to help people googling). 
Switching to Chrome helped (as it always does in recent years).